# inserting values from another table via a TRIGGER in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench, workbench

I need to create a **trigger** when a new record is added to the "plan" table, a record is automatically created in the "results" table.
Table "Plan" has columns:

- IdService
- IdEmployee
- Groupe
- Date
- Type (varchar)

Table "Results" has columns:

- IdService
- IdEmployee
- IdClient
- Date
- Result (varchar)
  But the idClient must be taken from table "Clients", corresponding to the group number added to the plan. Thus, the trigger should create not one, but several rows in the result table (since there can be several clients in one group)

I am attaching my code, but there is obviously an error in it

```sql
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydb`.`Plan_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `Plan` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into results (Result, idClient, Date, idService, idEmployee)
 values ('в процессе',idClient = (Select idClient from Clients
where Clients.Groupe = Plan.New.Groupe),
NEW.Date, NEW.idService, NEW.idEmployee);
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite OK only your subquery has ti return only one row, so it is better to limit it

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydb`.`Plan_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `Plan` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into results (Result, idClient, Date, idService, idEmployee)
 values ('в процессе',(Select idClient from Clients
where Clients.Groupe = New.Groupe ORDER BY idClient LIMIT 1),
NEW.Date, NEW.idService, NEW.idEmployee);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`results`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Results_Clients_idClient` FOREIGN KEY (`idClient`) REFERENCES `clients` (`idClient`))
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`Plan` (`Date`, `Groupe`, `Type`, `idService`, `idEmployee`) VALUES ('2020-01-15', '2', 'Мастер-класс', '4', '1')

Comment: @AngelinaMat i changed my answer, test this please

Comment: Yes it works! thanks a lot!!!!
Is it possible to make it so that several records are added to the results table (as many as there are people in the group)?